# What is the most practical way to persist user's shopping cart using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have been looking everywhere on the Internet about this issue. I encountered answers suggest using redux-persist package to store data in localstorage. However, I find this approach not really safe since the cart data is exposed in the developer tool and users can mess with the data easily. Other answers suggest that using the database in conjunction with cookie would be perfect however I don't really understand the process of this approach. Can anyone instruct me on this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is perfectly fine. This data always exists on the client - it does not matter if it exists in memory (Redux) or on disk (localStorage), the user *can and will probably* mess with it.

That means that your server can never trust anything the client sends him anyways. It will always have to validate information, or add it itself.

So, the client sending to the server "I buy 5 units of item 89 for a price of 2$ each" is never a sensible thing. The client would have to send "I buy 5 units of item 89" to the server. The server then needs to validate if this customer is allowed to buy item 89, if there are 5 units of it in stock and then look up the price from the database - and only then process the purchase.

=> Since you can never blindly trust client data, it is perfectly fine to store information in localStorage. You will have to validate that anyways.